# Select price range in Page Monitor with Regex (Addon Chrome)

Tags: regex

I installed an addon for chrome called "Page Monitor" that alerts you when a website changes. The difficulty is to alert when something specific happens using a Regex. (Also can be done in "selector" but I think it is more difficult)

The addon looks like that:

[image]

I have to insert the code into Regex there. I have been learning regex with several tutorials in Spanish or English, but I still have some doubts.

What I want to do is to detect if a price is in a specific range.

For example, if I choose a price range between $ 0.00 and $ 50.00, the tool must warn me when the price is $ 45.00, but it doesn't when the price is $ 55.00.

The website has very many prices.

I tried to use what I've learned, but doesn't seem to work:

```
<\B^[0.00-50.00]>
```

[image]

Could you help me to find a solution?

Comment: In the regex syntax, a character class can only define a range between two characters (i.e. all the characters that are between the two characters (included) in the ascii or unicode table). You can't define a numeric range with a character class (or only with integers lower than 10). Keep in mind that a regex engine is for characters and substrings, but doesn't care about numeric values. In other words, you can't write something like `[0-20]` but you can write something like `(?:1?[0-9]|20)`. Don't be afraid, and welcome in Stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a regex to match strings like `"$ 45.22", "$21.12", "$09.99" or "$ 2.30"`, while not matching any like these `$50.00, $ -12.00, $ 5, $ 49, $ 100.00`, following one will do the job:

```
\$ ?[0-4]?\d\.\d\d
```

however, you have to consult the addon manual/support forums to check what is the expected syntax for that tool..